# Pass Array value to a Variable

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-rm-template, azure-bicep

I'd like to variablise one element of an Array parameter that I'm passing to a Bicep template. Here's a cut down version of the Parameter file:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "value": "uksouth"
        },
        "networkSecurityGroupRules": {
            "value": [
                {
                    "name": "RDP",
                    "properties": {
                        "priority": 300,
                        "protocol": "TCP",
                        "access": "Allow",
                        "direction": "Inbound",
                        "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                        "sourcePortRange": "*",
                        "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                        "destinationPortRange": "3389"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "vnetName": {
            "value": "Dtldevopsagent"
        },
        "subnetName": {
            "value": "sandbox_subnet_2"
        },
        "virtualMachineName": {
            "value": "test-db"
        },
        "osDiskType": {
            "value": "Premium_LRS"
        },
        "dataDisks": {
            "value": [
                {
                    "lun": 0,
                    "createOption": "attach",
                    "caching": "ReadOnly",
                    "writeAcceleratorEnabled": false,
                    "id": null,
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'), '-_DataDisk_0')]'",
                    "storageAccountType": null,
                    "diskSizeGB": null,
                    "diskEncryptionSet": null
                },
                {
                    "lun": 1,
                    "createOption": "attach",
                    "caching": "None",
                    "writeAcceleratorEnabled": false,
                    "id": null,
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'),'-DataDisk_1')]",
                    "storageAccountType": null,
                    "diskSizeGB": null,
                    "diskEncryptionSet": null
                }
            ]
        },
        "dataDiskResources": {
           "value": [
            {
                "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'),'-DataDisk_0')]",
                "sku": "Premium_LRS",
                "properties": {
                    "diskSizeGB": 32,
                    "creationData": {
                        "createOption": "empty"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'),'-DataDisk_1')]",
                "sku": "Premium_LRS",
                "properties": {
                    "diskSizeGB": 32,
                    "creationData": {
                        "createOption": "empty"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
      },
    }
}
```

The Array parameter values I'm trying to set are **dataDisks.value.name** and **dataDiskResources.value.name**. I tried using `"[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'), '-_DataDisk_0')]'"` in order to set the Virtual Machine disk's name, but I got an error "The value of parameter disk.name is invalid.".

Is there a way I can pass these values to a Variable in my Bicep template file and only edit the "name" value of each of these two parameters? Or is there another way I can edit it?

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ***Parameters you can't `concat` value*** . It will error out with `"The value of parameter disk.name is invalid."`. ***Instead you can use Variables in both `Bicep ARM` or `JSON ARM`***.

**So your ARM template will be something link below :**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "uksouth"
        },
        "networkSecurityGroupRules": {
            "type": "array",
            "defaultValue": [
                {
                    "name": "RDP",
                    "properties": {
                        "priority": 300,
                        "protocol": "TCP",
                        "access": "Allow",
                        "direction": "Inbound",
                        "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                        "sourcePortRange": "*",
                        "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                        "destinationPortRange": "3389"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "vnetName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Dtldevopsagent"
        },
        "subnetName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "sandbox_subnet_2"
        },
        "virtualMachineName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "test-db"
        },
        "osDiskType": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Premium_LRS"
        }
    },
    "variables":{
        "dataDisks": [ 
                {
                    "lun": 0,
                    "createOption": "attach",
                    "caching": "ReadOnly",
                    "writeAcceleratorEnabled": false,
                    "id": null,
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'), '-_DataDisk_0')]",
                    "storageAccountType": null,
                    "diskSizeGB": null,
                    "diskEncryptionSet": null
                },
                {
                    "lun": 1,
                    "createOption": "attach",
                    "caching": "None",
                    "writeAcceleratorEnabled": false,
                    "id": null,
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'),'-DataDisk_1')]",
                    "storageAccountType": null,
                    "diskSizeGB": null,
                    "diskEncryptionSet": null
                }
            ],
        "dataDiskResources": [
            {
                "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'),'-DataDisk_0')]",
                "sku": "Premium_LRS",
                "properties": {
                    "diskSizeGB": 32,
                    "creationData": {
                        "createOption": "empty"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'),'-DataDisk_1')]",
                "sku": "Premium_LRS",
                "properties": {
                    "diskSizeGB": 32,
                    "creationData": {
                        "createOption": "empty"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "resources":[],
    "outputs": {
        "DatadiskName": {
          "value": "[variables('dataDisks')[0].name]",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "DatadiskResourceName": {
          "value": "[variables('dataDiskResources')[0].name]",
          "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

You can refer [`Variables in Bicep - Azure Resource Manager | Microsoft Docs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/variables) & [`Variables in templates - Azure Resource Manager | Microsoft Docs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/variables) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for this. I can see an example in the Bicep docs there for iterating over a number of disks in a variable. No idea how I missed that!